# I want to allow a single repeated value in a SQL Unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add a Unique constraint to a column in an sql table, however one of the requirements is that I have to allow multiple empty values and multiple entries with the string: "00000-00000-0000-0000", any other repeated value should not be allowed.

Is there any way to achieve this with a constraint?

I know that the unique constraint will allow me multiple null values but I also have to allow that special string.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a (primary) key in the table? Edit your question and preferably post the whole table structure as `CREATE TABLE` statement and if existing the `CREATE` statement of any index on it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that the unique constraint will allow me multiple null values
>   but I also have to allow that special string.

Unlike other DBMS software, SQL Server does not permit more than one `NULL` value with a unique constraint. NULL is considered a value for the purpose of unique constraint checking.

You can roll your own unique constraint with a unique filtered index for your need:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_YourTable_YourColumn ON dbo.YourTable(YourColumn)
WHERE YourColumn <> '00000-00000-0000-0000';
```

The above will also exclude `NULL` since the predicate result will be UNKNOWN rather than TRUE but, if by "empty" you mean an empty string, add that condition as well:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_YourTable_YourColumn ON dbo.YourTable(YourColumn)
WHERE YourColumn <> '00000-00000-0000-0000' AND YourColumn <> '';
```

Be mindful of [the required SET options for filtered indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) for sessions that modify the table which are listed below. These are mostly set as needed by modern client APIs.  However, I sometimes see stored procedures inadvertently created with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` and/or `ANSI_NULLS OFF`, which are "sticky" settings used at runtime and override the session settings.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Below is a query to identify problematic stored procs, which can be remediated by recreating them in a session with the options set properly:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName, name AS ProcedureName
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') = 0 
    OR OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'ExecIsAnsiNullsOn') = 0;
```

Comment: the link `the required SET options for filtered indexes` is linked back to this question ?

Comment: @Squirrel, thanks for the catch! This answer does includes those but my intent of course was to link to the official documentation.